# Show DIV or Section after redirecting to html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a problem with regards with showing DIV or section after redirecting to page, I am using magento custom page, so basically it is pure html.

Here's my code:
1st page:

```
1st page: <a href="otherpageurl"> 1st page </a>

second page:

<div id="secondpage_1st-div">
<h2>second page</h2>
<p>hello</p>
</div>

<div id="secondpage_2nd-div">
<h2>second page</h2>
<p>hello</p>
</div>
```

I need to show the div when I click the link on the first page.
I'm using tab to show content of every div

Thank you

Comment: Can you please be more clear. On clicking on the anchor tag, second page should open displaying its content(the two divs). Is it just that?

Comment: after clicking the 1st page link, it will show only 1 div on the other page (second page DIV)

Comment: of the two, only one should be shown? Right? That is div with id 'secondpage_1st-div'

Comment: Yeah, only one should be shown, only one div. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript to hide the div with id 'secondpage_2nd-div' in second page!

```
<script>
    element=document.getElementById("secondpage_2nd-div");
    element.style.display = 'none';           // Hide
    //element.style.display = 'block';          // Show
</script>
```

Else, there are many div in page, hide all the divs and show only one desired,

```
<script>
    var divs = ​document.getElementsByTagName("div");​
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.display = 'none';        
    }
</script>
```

and then

```
<script>
    element=document.getElementById("secondpage_1st-div");
    element.style.display = 'block';           // show one div
</script
```

It totally depends on your requirement.
Hope it helps!

Comment: where will I add the code? inside the anchor tag of the first page? or second page?

Comment: In your second page!