# Hide div after redirecting to new HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two html pages index.html and register.html
From index.html I need to go to register.html and show Login page after skipping select region. below is the code I am trying.

```
$("#lgnToProfile").on("click", function(){
window.location.href = "register.html";
$("#slctRgn").hide();
$("#lgnPage").show();
});
```

Can anyone check and suggest me how to resolve this and what I am doing wrong?

I referred the solutions provide at [Show DIV or Section after redirecting to html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406149/show-div-or-section-after-redirecting-to-html-page) But no success.

Comment: Once you move the user to register.html. The code won't run on the next page.

Comment: Who sees the div got hidden after they changed the page?

Comment: I am not sure, why people downvoted on my question. I didn't think, it was some foolish question. I think I have made my question clear and tried alternatives too. Its not something which is very repetetive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you navigate to a new page, none of the Javascript that ran on the previous page has any effect anymore.

What you would need to do, is somehow inform `register.html` that it needs to hide the select region div and then hide the div from a script running in `register.html`.

For example, from `index.html` you could add a query string parameter to notify `register.html`.

```
$("#lgnToProfile").on("click", function() {
    window.location.href = "register.html?hideSlctRgn=1";
}
```

Then, from `register.html`, *on document ready*, check if the parameter is set and hide the div accordingly.

```
$(function() {
    if ( window.location.search.indexOf('hideSlctRgn=1') != -1 ) {
        $("#slctRgn").hide();
        $("#lgnPage").show();
    }
})
```

There are other (better) ways to test for the existence of a query string parameter, but the above is a simple way. Instead of a query string parameter you could set a cookie, or perhaps use local storage.

Comment: Thank you this was the simplest of the solution, which resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modifie your URL path, you can do it with "localStorage":

```
var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
var savedPath   = localStorage.getItem('previousPage');

// if a page has been saved yet
if (typeof savedPath === 'string') {

    // if the current page is "register.html" and the saved page is "index.html"
    if (currentPath.match('/register.html') && savedPath.match('/index.html')) {
        $("#slctRgn").hide();
        $("#lgnPage").show();
    }
}

// save current page
localStorage.setItem('previousPage', currentPath);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the referer page to take further action on the next page. Because JavaScript can’t access the referer page, you could achieve that using an anchor or hash to check for the referer and show/hide your elements.

On `index.html` you just need the link (no `click`jQuery event needed) to the registration page appending a hash name: `register.html#referer`. The word `referer` could be whatever you want to.

Then on `register.html` you need to evaluate the hash value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // get the hash value
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    // if the hash is defined and it’s equal to “referer” (the choosen hash value)
    if(hash == "#referer") {

        // execute your code to show or hide elements

    }

});
```